# How to connect Spring App to AWS SNS using IAM Roles?

Tags: spring-cloud-aws

I have a spring boot app and I want to connect it to my AWS SNS using `spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging`. I've seen tutorials on how to do it using AWS SECRET ACCCESS KEY but I want to use IAM Roles instead. Do you know any example or tutorial on how to do it ?

Cheers

Comment: any solution for that